# mysql time_stamp format

Tags: mysql, date

I have a stored time_stamp in a table and I want to format it from the YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS to show up as Oct 19th 2011.

I'm a bit new at this, but I'm thinking I need to set a new variable that takes that time_stamp and convert it.

```
$mydate = DATEFORMAT(columnName, %b-%D-%Y);
```

Its not quite working for me am I on the right track?

Thanks folks

I got the date thing correct now I think.. its just not showing the date. I've got a loop that goes through each row till there are no more:

```
$query  = "SELECT comment, DATE_FORMAT(postdate, '%b %D %Y') FROM sessionscomments WHERE session = 'Geoarge'";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{

    echo    "<div id=fav>";
    echo    strip_tags( "Date: {$row['postdate']}");
```

So do I still need to make my formatted date into a variable so that it will format it with each row?

Comment: Try adding the `AS`: `SELECT comment, DATE_FORMAT(postdate, '%b %D %Y') AS postdate FROM ...`.

Comment: it doesn't like my "while statement" now

Comment: does AS need the : or ()

Comment: No, your query should work with `SELECT comment, DATE_FORMAT(postdate, '%b %D %Y') AS postdate FROM sessionscomments WHERE session = 'Geoarge'`, although I'd use another name, like `postdate_formatted`, just for clarity. What error message do you get?

Comment: sweet you rule!! I didn't realize that that was a variable. THANKS SOO MUCH

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do the formatting in an SQL query, you can use the [DATE_FORMAT() function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) in MySQL.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%b %D %Y') AS my_date
FROM tableName;
```

Formatting the date in PHP, you'll want to use the [date() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) in PHP.

```
$my_date = date('M jS Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: ... where $timestamp is the raw value in the database timestamp field

Answer (score 1):

You're definitely on the right track!

The difference from your example is that you need to specify the date format as a string - you can do this by surrounding it in single quotes (`'`) and remove the hyphens (`-`):

```sql
DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%b %D %Y')
```

By the way, if you're just using this in a normal `SELECT` query, you can place this expression inline in place of a column name, and give it a name using the `AS` keyword. For example:

```
SELECT someColumn, anotherColumn, DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%b %D %Y') AS formattedDate
```

which might return something like:

```
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| someColumn | anotherColumn | formattedDate |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1          | 2             | Oct 19th 2011 |
| 2          | 6             | Feb 26th 1989 |
+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking exclusively in mysql and not other language that connects to mysql. I hope this helps:

```
DATE_FORMAT(columnName, '%b %D %Y')
```

Comment: oh actually I'm trying to echo it into php. Does this make a difference? That's why I was trying to set it as a variable.

Comment: If you extract a row from a table to variable `$row` that has a column  named `col` you can echo it by converting the value to a timestamp and then formatting it: `echo date("M jS Y", strtotime($row['column']));` ([PHP date](http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)).